# Automating EC2 Instances register/deregister from ELB during Jenkins job build

Tags: jenkins, amazon-ec2, continuous-integration, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to build the binaries to be deployed on my production server. The source code is being managed in SVN and in Jenkins, I am using the parameterized plugin to allow the team members to select the tags they want to deploy.

Currently, the production setup is that multiple instances running behind the ELB. So in order to deploy the build, what I need to do that take out (deregister) the instances one by one and deploy the build on that server (in order to prevent downtime).

I am looking for a Jenkins plugin (if available) which could help me in automating that task which could take out one instance from ELB, deploy the latest build and then again register that instance to the ELB and repeat the same steps for all the instances.

NOTE: Instances can be dynamic in count as autoscaling can increase or decrease the instances behind the ELB.

Answer (score 0):

If your build produces a docker container then you can use EKS or ECS to automate the deployment. Theses services will take care of deployment of your new version of service side by side without any downtime. Additionally you can also set the scaling policies to increase or decrease the no of service instances based on the load.

Comment: Thanks, Vinoth. We do have a plan to move to Docker container, but currently, our services are directly running on EC2 Instances behind ELB. Is there no way I could achieve it with our current deployment setup.